# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: 'sudo gdebi -n tableau-server-<version>_amd64.deb' error version:No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install a Tableau server on Ubuntu 16.04 following the instructions given on [this page](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/guides/everybody-install-linux/en-us/everybody_admin_install_linux.htm).

But the step below gives me this error:

```
$> sudo gdebi -n tableau-server-<version>_amd64.deb
Error:
-bash:version: No such file or directory
```

Please can you explain, why this message arrives and how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `<version>` field by the real version of the software you are installing.

The error thrown by the shell (here, `bash`) is that it complains about the fact that it does not find the file `version` because the characters `<` and `>` usually need a file on one side of it.

I think you did not realize but the `tableau-server-<version>_amd64.deb` refer to a file that should have downloaded at some point on your computer. You need to find a file like `tableau-server-1.2.4_amd64.deb` (this is just an example).

Just find this file and write the full name of this `.deb` file with the proper version number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did install the correct version in windows.But the problem is, I don't know how I can locate (syntax) the windows directory in ubuntu environment and refer to the exact file. Any help on this would be great!!

Comment: I do not even understand your question... What do you mean by "*I don't know how I can locate (syntax) the windows directory in ubuntu environment and refer to the exact file.*" ?

Comment: Yes you are right, that I had to type the exact server name.I wrote the exact version. Error: gdebi error,file not found. My downloaded tableau server file is located in c:/ in windows. I have asked in the earlier question, how do i let ubuntu know that the file location is c:/.

Comment: How do you run your Ubuntu on the top of a MS-Windows machine? Is it a virtual machine? If so, you need to download this file from inside the virtual machine, in order to make it reachable from the Ubuntu (you can use the `wget` command, beware you might need to install `wget` before using it: `sudo apt-get install wget`).

Comment: Its a virtual machine. One monitor connected to my docking station where Windows is installed. Another monitor to CPU where its runs on Ubuntu.